# App Metrics .netCore 3.0 does not tracking endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, influxdb

When I using App Metric to report into influxDb for an web API with .netcore 2.1, it return the calling enpoint info like the image
[image: .netcore 2.1]

But when I upgrade it to .netcore 2.2 or 3.1 then it return nothing
[image: .netcore 2.2]

Is it wrong in config some thing when i upgrade?
Looking for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it worked after adding .AddMetrics() right behind .AddMvc() in Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
....
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
....
services.AddMvc().AddMetrics()....
}
```